# Emails Sent From My Site Do Not Get Delivered to Gmail

Tags: gmail, smtp

I am currently working on a project for a client and we're having issues sending emails from the site (like welcome emails, complaints, etc...). The emails actually get delivered to hotmail and yahoo mail, but not to GMail. One thing to note is that I'm using gmail as my smtp server and I believe my smtp configurations are correct, but I really do not know why emails are not being delivered to gmail (not even to the junk mail).

Here's how I've configured the smtp server in my Web.config file:

```
<mailSettings>
  <smtp deliveryMethod="Network">
    <network host="smtp.gmail.com" 
             userName="out@mydomain.com" 
             password="******" 
             port="587" 
             enableSsl="true" />
  </smtp>
</mailSettings>
```

Any thoughts why this might be happening?

Comment: Google has a daily limit to the number of emails you can send in a given day.  If you are masking the sender its very likely Google is filtering it as spam.

Comment: Does it happen with any gmail email address? Try sending it to a different @gmail.com.

Comment: @Ramhound: I'm not sending many emails per day, we're still testing the site so it's nothing more than 3-5 emails per day. And what do you mean by masking the sender? I have the same address set in the smtp configurations and in the FROM field of the email.

Comment: @Greg: I tried. But it is not being delivered to any gmail account. Is there some way I could track what is happening to the email and where it is going?

Answer (score 0):

Ksaem, it is hard to figure out why it is being blocked with the information at hand, but clearly that gmail to gmail issue is the problem, and I doubt you will over come it.

If you have business-class Internet service, I suggest that you try their SMTP relayer. If you do not, Google "smtp relay service" (without the quotes). You can purchase service for about $25/year.